# 'static' text not adding in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I was wondering 'static' text not perpending to static files. In settings file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
...,
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
...,
)  

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

In My templates,

```
{% load staticfiles %}
  <title>Knowlarity Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/bootstrap.css' %}">
  <script src="{% static '/js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static '/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
```

But when I refresh page in browser it is giving 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/bootstrap.min.js
not 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/bootstrap.min.js
But if I hard coded It is fine.
The 'static' text not adding ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to remove the leading slash, like so:

```
{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}
```

Comment: excellent, Can you tell me the reason why it is behaves like this ?

Comment: the leading slash makes it an absolute path (starting from your root), plus your STATIC_URL already contains a trailing slash.

Answer (score 0):

django adds trailing slashes to nearly everything for consistency in url patterns 'i.e. "/static" == "/static/"' and to avoid confusion for users visiting your app. looks like the template was rendering with '/static//js/jquery.js'.